# tools for doing c++/java symbian development

Tags: sdk, symbian, s60, carbide

I want to do some small application development for S60 3rd edition, FP2 of OS version 9.3 (target platform). What are the steps i need to do to start my development? what development OS do i need? windows or linux?

Can i install carbide/java/c++ for linux?

What is the preferred approach?

http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Tools_and_downloads/Other/
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbide.c%2B%2B

really confusing info in those wiki pages. it seems to suggest that i need symbian OS device to use carbide++? doesn't make much sense to me

Comment: why you don't use qt? http://qt.nokia.com/products/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's better to use [Qt Sdk](http://qt.nokia.com/products/) . it is product of Nokia company