# symbian simulator/ debugging in 9.3

Tags: symbian, qt-creator, nokia

This question is a very close follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9729780/170521)

I'm very new indeed to all the symbian application development environment thing, and one of the main things that is currently dragging me to advance is that i recently installed latest qt creator (2.4.1) + qt sdk (4.7.4), and when i debug one of the sample applications i can't see any option whatsoever that would allow me to choose the hardware platform i want to compile with.

is it the remote compiler or something else? i clicked in start debugging and i got a default simulator view, but i don't see what symbian version is the simulator running, or where or how should i change that?

i want to test and build applications for the Symbian 9.3 edition (3750 ExM models)

Comment: note to myself: reading this http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/S60_3rd_Edition:_Application_Development